# Show that $g(z) =\bar{z}$ is continuous at every point of $\mathbb{C}$ and that it's not differentiable at any point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $g(z) =\bar{z}$ is continuous at every point of $\mathbb{C}$ and that it's not differentiable at any point.

Answer (score 2):

To see continuity, remember that $\overline{z} - \overline{w} = \overline{z-w}$ for any $z,w \in \Bbb{C}$, and that $|\overline{z}| = |z|$ for any $z \in \Bbb{C}$. So if you can understand why $f(z) = z$ is continuous, it is easy to see why $g(z) = \overline{z}$ is continuous.

To see why $g(z) = \overline{z}$ is not differentiable anywhere, recall the definition of differentiability: $g$ is differentiable at a point $c$ if and only if
$$
\lim_{z \to c} \frac{g(z)-g(c)}{z-c} = \lim_{z \to c} \frac{\overline{z} - \overline{c}}{z - c}
$$
exists (and is finite). But if this limit exists, it should be the same no matter how $z$ approaches $c$. This is where the problem lies. Suppose $z$ approaches $c$ in such a way that the real parts of $z$ and $c$ are always the same. Then the limit will be $-1$. Suppose instead that the *imaginary* parts of $z$ and $c$ are always the same as $z$ approaches $c$. Then the limit will be $1$. This means the limit can't exist, so $g$ is not differentiable at $c$.