# Show that $\lvert z\rvert$ is not differentiable anywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

Without using Cauchy-Riemann.

I know the trick is to make $z_0 + \Delta z \rightarrow z_0 $ along a circle so that $ \lvert z_0 + \Delta z\rvert $ stays constant- small changes in the domain do not lead to small changes in the range. But I'm not sure how to prove it.

This is not the same as showing that $g(z) =\bar{z}$ is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: You can show that it is not a conformal map.

Comment: better http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232372/show-that-gz-barz-is-continuous-at-every-point-of-mathbbc-and-that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $g(z) =\bar{z}$ is continuous at every point of $\mathbb{C}$ and that it's not differentiable at any point.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232372/show-that-gz-barz-is-continuous-at-every-point-of-mathbbc-and-that)

Comment: @MyGlasses The OP is requesting a proof without the CREs.  The possible duplicate uses the CREs.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes. Second link prepares this.

Comment: Well, I would not call that a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(z)=|z|$.  Then, $f$ is differentiable then the limit $\lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}$ exists and is independent of the manner in which $\Delta z$ approaches $0$.

Suppose $\Delta z=\Delta x$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{|z+\Delta x|-|z|}{\Delta x}&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{|z+\Delta x|^2-|z|^2}{\Delta x(|z+\Delta x|+|z|)}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{2x+|\Delta x|}{(|z+\Delta x|+|z|)}\\\\
&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Instead, suppose that $\Delta z=iy$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\Delta y\to 0}\frac{|z+i\Delta y|-|z|}{i\Delta y}&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{|z+i\Delta y|^2-|z|^2}{i\Delta y(|z+i\Delta y|+|z|)}\\\\
&=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{2y+|\Delta y|}{i(|z+\Delta y|+|z|)}\\\\
&=\frac{-iy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Since $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equal, the limit of interest fails to exist and hence $f$ is nowhere differentiable.